# Jest tests in an Expo app with react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, react-native-paper

I have an Expo app that I'm setting up. I've added Jest tests and they work fine. I want to use react-native-paper for styling but when I add that and modify the one page I have so far to use it the test I've wriiten fails  due to problems with the imports and I'm stuck so far as to how to fix it.

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@expo/ngrok": "^4.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.4",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    env: {
      production: {
        plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
      },
    },
  };
};
```

When I run the test I get the following error

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ jest
 FAIL  pages/Home.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: {omitted path}/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/index.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

      2 | import "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect";
      3 | import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react-native"
    > 4 | import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
        | ^

      at new SourceMap (../../node_modules/@babel/generator/src/source-map.ts:61:42)
      at new Generator (../../node_modules/@babel/generator/src/index.ts:24:35)
      at generate (../../node_modules/@babel/generator/src/index.ts:271:15)
      at generateCode (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/file/generate.ts:35:22)
      at run (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/index.ts:59:48)
          at run.next (<anonymous>)
      at transform (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:29:20)
          at transform.next (<anonymous>)
      at evaluateSync (../../node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
      at fn (../../node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
      at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.ts:97:14)
      at transformSync (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:66:52)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:464:35)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (pages/Home.test.tsx:4:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.208 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by adding `react-native-paper` to the `transformIgnorePatterns` in my package.json so it now looks like this:

```
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)|react-native-paper"
    ],
```

Comment: thanks man, this is such a recurring issue, should be documented better imo